# Having problems with URL rewriting using Nginx

Tags: cakephp, nginx, url-rewriting

I’m running Centos 7 with Nginx and can’t seem to configure the URL rewriting correctly.

I'm trying to install Passbolt, a password manager (using [this](https://medium.com/passbolt/passbolt-on-centos-7-with-nginx-php7-fpm-mariadb-from-scratch-7b2a9b15f3a4) guide).

My config:

```
server {
  listen 80;


client_body_buffer_size     100K;
  client_header_buffer_size   1k;
  client_max_body_size        100k;
  large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

client_body_timeout   10;
  client_header_timeout 10;
  keepalive_timeout     5 5;
  send_timeout          10;

root /var/www/passbolt;

# X-Frame-Options is to prevent from clickJacking attack
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

#  disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

# This header enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

# This will enforce HTTP browsing into HTTPS and avoid ssl stripping attack
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php;
  }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.+)$;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param           SERVER_NAME $http_host;
  }

location ~* \.(jpe?g|woff|woff2|ttf|gif|png|bmp|ico|css|js|json|pdf|zip|htm|html|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?|txt|wav|swf|svg|avi|mp\d)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    try_files $uri /app/webroot/$uri /index.php?$args;
  }
}
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I’m unable to view the web application that I set up, when I try and reach it all I get is a 404 error. When doing a healthcheck, something passbolt does, I get errors saying I have issues in the config.

Comment: 404 means a configuration or path issue. Hard to say what is wrong from here. Check if the file paths are correct